# Why is my POST method returning "Unauthorized"? C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

http://static.pmmlabs.ru/OpenPeriscope/

I follow the documentation under "Authentication" where they provide examples and error responses. I am currently receiving this error message when I call my POST-method:

```
401 Unauthorized This endpoint requires authentication and no cookie value was provided, or is invalid
```

The token should absolutely contain the correct value so I assume it has to be something with the code. This is my current code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
string json = "{" +
            "\"bundle_id\":\"\"," +
            "\"phone_number\":\"\"," +
            "\"session_key\":\"" + key + "\"," +
            "\"session_secret\":\"" + secret + "\"," +
            "\"user_id\":\"" + userid + "\"," +
            "\"user_name\":\"" + name + "\"," +
                        "\"vendor_id\":\"81EA8A9B-2950-40CD-9365-40535404DDE4\"" +
                        "}";
var content = new StringContent(json);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.periscope.tv/api/v2/loginTwitter", content);
var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseJson);
```

The JSON I put together is also valid. If I write it out in the log it looks like this:

```
{"bundle_id":"","phone_number":"","session_key":"752365274-loPQJPpyAtwuqcJJtTqk7KlRgbdGgVQ5ahBWuItr","session_secret":"2hY9kLYCwKC3rIGGMlCt523uOy08zc8SEc7w6WSlLLViD","user_id":"752365274","user_name":"My username","vendor_id":"81EA8A9B-2950-40CD-9365-40535404DDE4"}
```

I came across a post where a user successfully made it work but it was with "HttpWebRequest" method that I cannot use because I am coding in Xamarin Forms (PCL). [Using Twitter login API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684558/using-twitter-login-api)

If you check his answer to his own post you can see the sample code.

How can I adjust my current code in order to successfully get the JSON response?

UPDATE:

Parameters/tokens should be correct. Been trying with different solutions/codestructures but it keeps giving me "Unauthorized". This is the last code I tried to use (tried to mimic the project that I linked that works):

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "session_secret", secret},
            { "user_id", userid},
            { "phone_number", ""},
            { "vendor_id", ""},
            { "bundle_id", "com.bountylabs.periscope"},
            { "session_key", key},
            { "user_name", username}
        };

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
        MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonRequest));
        HttpContent content = new StreamContent(jsonStream);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.periscope.tv/api/v2/loginTwitter", content);
        var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseJson);
        var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Don't build your JSON this way. If some variable contains ", it all goes bad.

Comment: yeah I usually build it with a dictionary but the working example with the http request method used this so that is why I used the same

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is some problem with the authorization session key or secret.
If I were in your place, I would test my request using some other client in order to make sure I am passing correct parameters (especially for "session_key" and "session_secret").

In order to do this test quickly and simply, I would recommend using the "Restlet Client - DHC" which is a Chrome extension client:

You can add this extension using the below link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-dhc/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en

Comment: This is so strange. I have tried for hours but I just get the same response "unauthorized". This is the example they provide on the documentation: 

`POST /api/v2/loginTwitter HTTP/1.1
Host: api.periscope.tv
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 291
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: en-GB;q=1, en;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, ja;q=0.6, nl;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Periscope/3313 (iPhone; iOS 7.1.1; Scale/2.00)`

Do I maybe need to add code concerning `gzip, deflate`?

Comment: Actually I am not sure if you need to do so. But as I mentioned before, it will be more clear if you tried to test the request using some other client, so that you will finally have a clear idea where the problem is.

Comment: I am 95 % confident that my tokens/parameters that I am sending are correct (I have tried with a lot of different methods with the same result) so I feel like it must be something like that missing

Comment: What about the user_id parameter?

Comment: yeah it should also be correct. I get it from my Xamarin.Auth function. `string userid = e.Account.Properties["user_id"]`

Comment: Well.. one other thing to try, do you have any working application that successfully gets the JSON response? In case you have one, you can track what is the exact request it sends to the API using Fiddler.

Comment: No i do not. However the HttpRequest project that I linked is supposed to work. If you check out that code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684558/using-twitter-login-api (check his answer) he is using a `StreamWriter` so instead of using a `StringContent` maybe I am supposed to use a `StreamContent`instead?

Comment: Updated the post with another code-snippet that I have used. Gives me the same result though. I tried to use "StreamContent" instead of "StringContent"